# How to extract TLS 1.X of all app services/web app running Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently searching away to extract a list of app services/web apps which are still using old TLS 1.0/1.1 from Azure.

Could you please help me with with?

Many thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried in my environment. Please try the below powershell command to list all the apps with their tls minimum versions of "1.1 "or "1.0"***

```
$groupname = "groupname”
$apps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $groupname
$names = $apps.Name
foreach($name in $names){
    $tls = (Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $groupname -Name $name).SiteConfig.MinTlsVersion

if ($tls -eq “1.1” -Or  $tls -eq “1.0”) {

    Write-Host "minTlsVersion of web app" $name "is" $tls
}
}
```

***Output :***

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Venkatesan, I appreciate your quick reply!  I had another question, we have multiple subscriptions 90 ish, how can I pull out the same results from multiple subscription or resource groups?